# Android 2d and 3d synchornization

Tags: android

Is there any way to synchronize 2d and 3d animations in android.
Let me explain:
    i want to run a normal zoom/move/ animation of an android widget using surface view.
    Same time i want a 3d cube rotation using Glsurface.

Can i achieve a parallel animation effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you implement the animations. It could very well be enough to set the duration of both animations to exactly the same, and then start them at the same time.
As far as I know there is no "AnimationProgress" listener that you can use to get how far the 2d animation has progressed, so if you need a very exact synchronization of the two animations, you might be best off running your own animation thread updating the position of both objects continuously.

Comment: But the drawing pipeline for 2d and 3d animation are different.

Comment: @sudipm true, but I assume that you have some global controller object that can start the animation?

Comment: Can i use a GL surface view to achieve this :for 2d animations extract android.graphics.canvas from the surface holder of the GLSurfaceView and use it , for 3d animations: use the GL context available with the GLSurfaceView to do 3d animations.i use one thread to run both 2d and 3d drawings.I tried to synchronize them using "eglWaitNative(EGL11.EGL_CORE_NATIVE_ENGINE, getHolder())" and "eglWaitGL()".   But while running my android device hangs with the below message: W/SharedBufferStack( 1364): waitForCondition(DequeueCondition) timed out (identity=6, status=0). CPU may be pegged.please help

Comment: @sudipm no, I don't think that is a good idea. You should have some object, such as you application-implementation that can tell both the GL-thread and the SurfaceView thread to start their animations. The two different threads should not need to interact with eachother.